# com.google.android.gms.common.api.apiexception: 10: на разных устройствах

Tags: android

Мы с товарищем делаем совместное приложение для Android. На данный момент каждый из нас делал самостоятельно авторизацию. У него все работает как нужно, но когда я хочу запустить его код на своем устройстве, на процессе входа со своим аккаутном Google я ловлю ошибку com.google.android.gms.common.api.apiexception: 10. Авторизация с помощью Google с использованием Firebase. Мне кажется, что проблема как-то связана с SHA-1. Как я могу решить эту проблему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было создать новый SHA-1  и добавить его в проект.